# Error in Web Config in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

ASP.NET WebForms and i am making authentication for users , but i get this error in web.config file:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message:  sections are allowed only within
>    sections.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 38:      Line 39:      Line 40:     Line 41:     Line 42:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Users\dunja\Desktop\webapp1\web.config
>   Line: 40

Here is content of Web.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="webapp1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Gy;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/User/User.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>

   <location path="Admin">

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>

  </location>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks to all !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your **location** tag just before closing the **configuration** tag, just like this

```
<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps...!

Answer (score 2):

Your location section should be specified outside the `<system.web>` tag and inside the `<location>` section you  need to add `<system.web>` tags. Please refer the modified config file below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="webapp1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Gy;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
<location path="Admin">
  <system.Web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.Web>
</location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/User/User.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>


  </system.web>
</configuration>
```